# Putting name while importing a file

Tags: php, import, filenames

I want to give a custom name to the file which i want to import. So in the import page i have two text field `<input type='text' name='f[]' value='http://'>|<input type='text' name='n[]'>`.
When i put only the url of the file in the text area without putting any name, the file is uploaded and the file takes the basename of the url. But i want to give a custom name to the file while uploading it. So to do this when i put the url of the file and my own custom name in the two text field, some different name is coming like "file_0.dat". I have tried to get the name using $_POST[n], but it didnt work. I am sharing a part of the import action script. Please help me in this regard.

```
$i=0;

    if(trim($_POST['n'][$i]) == '')
        $_name = preg_match("~(.*)\.(\w)~i",basename($f)) ? basename($f) : "file_$i.dat";
    else
        $_name = preg_match("~(.*)\.(\w)~i",basename($_POST['n'][$i])) ? basename($_POST['n'][$i]) : "file_$i.dat";
```

Comment: I am confused a bit. To do a file upload you have to do `type="file"`. How are you uploading just by URL. Are you downloading the file separately ?

Comment: i am uploading the file with snoopy. But i want to give a custom name to the file. Is the script above ok ?

Comment: If you are asking how to just change the name of the file, you can do that using the PHP `rename` function after the file has been uploaded. If you are asking why your file is getting the name `file_0.dat`, its because the base name is not matching the regular expression you have given. Do you want us to test the regex?

Comment: Yes please. what should be the preg_match expression so that it will match with whatever filename i give ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking how to just change the name of the file, you can do that using the PHP `rename` function after the file has been uploaded.

```
rename(basename($f), "/path_to_file/my_file.txt");
```

If you are asking why your file is getting the name `file_0.dat`, its because the base name is not matching the regular expression you have given.

Try this regex expression.

```
$filename = 'abc.zip';
$name = preg_match('/^(.)*/i', $filename) ? $filename : "file_$i.dat";
print($name);
```

This matches `all` the characters (case insensitive). It will always match whatever filename you give and `will never go to the else part`.

But for filenames you dont want this. You dont want to have **"special characters"** in your filename. The correct regex that I would recommend is to allow only:

1. letters and numbers
2. _, ., -
3. The extension must only be numbers and letters.
4. The size of extension must be 3 or 4.'

This regex is what I use:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\d]{1}[\w\-\s]+.[\w\d]{3,4}/i', $filename)
```

This will allow the first character to only be letters or number. From second character to period(.) it will allow letter, number, -, and _. Then the extension can be 3 or 4 chars long. Extension must be letter or number.

Comment: Hey `$name = preg_match('/^(.)*/i', $filename) ? $filename : "file_$i.dat";` worked for me. Thanks a lot. Can you tell me what was the problem before in the script ?

Comment: @AmitPal I genuienly dont know what `~` is used for. Maybe you can tell me. Maybe then I can tell you more clearly your issue with regex. But apart from that, regex live in between / and / e.g. `/pattern/` Then you also dont need to escape `.` Also as I mentioned, please dont use (.)* as it can contain special characters. Use the second regex that I gave in bottom of my answer